# Listbox not displaying new Items

Tags: vb.net

For years on end I found every solution to my problems discussed and solved on stackoverflow, and now I am puzzled that the first thing I actually post myself is this:

```
    Public Shared Sub DisplayCIntervals()
    Dim Scratch As Integer


    IntervalSets.ListBox1.Items.Clear()
    IntervalSets.ListBox1.Items.Add("Name" + Chr(9) + Chr(9) + "Gruppe" + Chr(9) + Chr(9) + "Start" + Chr(9) + Chr(9) + "Ende")

    While CurrentIntervals(Scratch, 8) <> Nothing
        IntervalSets.ListBox1.Items.Add(CurrentIntervals(Scratch, 6) + Chr(9) + CurrentIntervals(Scratch, 7) + CurrentIntervals(Scratch, 0) + ":" + CurrentIntervals(Scratch, 1) + ":" + CurrentIntervals(Scratch, 2) + Chr(9) + CurrentIntervals(Scratch, 3) + ":" + CurrentIntervals(Scratch, 4) + ":" + CurrentIntervals(Scratch, 5))
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(CurrentIntervals(Scratch, 6) + Chr(9) + CurrentIntervals(Scratch, 7) + CurrentIntervals(Scratch, 0) + ":" + CurrentIntervals(Scratch, 1) + ":" + CurrentIntervals(Scratch, 2) + Chr(9) + CurrentIntervals(Scratch, 3) + ":" + CurrentIntervals(Scratch, 4) + ":" + CurrentIntervals(Scratch, 5))
        Scratch += 1
    End While
    End Sub
```

In my Application the user can create, save and load time intervals. There is a form in which these intervals can be created and saved, and I would like to have it display the currently loaded intervals on form.activate with this Sub.
IntervalSets.Listbox1.Items.Add commands are not executed inside the while loop. The loop itself, though, works as I would like it to, and the writeline outputs print the expected strings.

I triedListbox1.Hide() -> Listbox1.Show() as well as Listbox1.Refresh(), both don't change anything.

What am I missing here?!

Cheers,

Marc

Comment: Yeah, they are executed. If you're seeing output on the console then they must be being executed.  The fact that you don't get the expected result doesn't mean the code isn't being execute. It means that you're doing something wrong. The most likely issue that I can see is that you are referring to the default instance of `IntervalSets` in that code. Did you actually display the default instance in the first place? If not then you're adding the items to a form that you haven't displayed, so of course you won't see them.

Comment: Indeed I could solve the problem by creating a public instance of the form and handing its name to the sub. thank you very much sir! What a rookie mistake.

Comment: Don't "hand its name" to the sub; **pass an actual reference to the Form** into that sub.  Better yet, why is this code outside of the Form at all?...it's tightly coupled to the Form as it is manipulating the ListBox directly.  Move that code into the Form and remove the `Shared` keyword as that is simply going to cause you more problems.

Comment: You are correct, of course.

Comment: I was working on an app for (mostly) myself and my workgroup to work with and every now and then I was adding forms / functions just to get something to work quickly as far as it gives me the necessary output and also my colleagues can use it...I received no formal education in programming, so I'm always thankful for comments like yours in order to get a better grasp on where to best put certain subs / functions / declarations in my next projects. So thankful indeed I made the effort to express it half a year later ;) happy holidays!